# Multilevel Category sliders for mobile device

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I am trying to create category options of my website for mobile devices. I want to create it in a way that when you click on a "Categories" in a new slide it shows the list of categories and when you tap on any category it shows in a new slide the list of sub categories. 
Please let me know what is the best way to create it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how large the data is. If it's small simply return the data as `{'category': ['sub ca1', 'sub ca2']}` and the client will render it.

If it's a large dataset create 2 endpoints:

1. an endpoint that will return all categories (or a range of categories), for example: `url/categories`
2. an endpoint that will return the subcategories to a specific category, example: `url/categories/1/subcategories`